# How can I configure kube-proxy to connect via https to apiserver?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

Reading the documentation from http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-proxy/ it doesn't look like I can connect to the apiserver via https.

The same goes for scheduler and controller-manager, but those two maybe are supposed to run on the same machine as the apiserver and can connect via localhost.

But what about the proxy? This is supposed to connect remotely to the apiserver. Is it possible to configure authentication and/or authorization from the proxy to the apiserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing. Looks like all daemons support a "--kubeconfig" flag that gives access to public and private key for authorization.